# Azure OCR is skipping some values (especially numbers)

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I created a simple grid on a paper with numbers and it skips some numbers. I tested it on multiple models and it seems Azure OCR is really skipping some numbers.

Anyone did a succesfully grid (or similar) that do not skip data? Maybe some design patterns that increase consistency?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/#detect-text

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-US/services/cognitive-services/ - sample

Comment: You are using the older version of OCR engine available in Azure. This engine has some flaws but can support a wide range of (human) languages. The newest engine is called 'Read API' that is a lot more accurate and can process handwritten and printed text. However, it only supports English: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text

Answer (score 0):

Azure [Form Recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/curl-train-extract) is a cognitive service that uses machine learning technology to identify and extract key-value pairs and table data from form documents. The  Supported types: pdf, image/jpeg, image/png.Can you try this one?